# Private API Enterprise account - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, enterprise, iphone-privateapi, core-telephony

I have to use some Apple private API (in particular Core telephony framework).

I have a doubt:

is it possible to use it and then distribute app by iOS Enterprise account?

To clarify:
I dont want to distribute app on store by only in my company by enterprise distribution

Comment: Apps distributed via an enterprise signing certificate do not need to go through App Review, so you can use private API.

Comment: It is possible but many private APIs these days are protected by entitlements (including core telephony). You can call them but they won't work. For that you need jailbreak.

Comment: @creker I'm new with Private API. what do you mean for "entitlements"? Have I to pay for use it?